# Why can one specify the size of an array in a function parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I don't understand why the following example compiles and works:

```
void printValues(int nums[3], int length) {
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        std::cout << nums[i] << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

It seems that the size of 3 is completely ignored but putting an invalid size results in a compile error. What is going on here?

Comment: by invalid size, you mean negative?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: yes, and zero

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you do sizeof(nums)?

Comment: @Ray Hidayat: If declared as above, you'll get `sizeof(int *)` - a pointer size, regardless of what size is specified in the array declaration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++ (as well as in C), parameters declared with array type always immediately decay to pointer type. The following three declarations are equivalent

```
void printValues(int nums[3], int length);
void printValues(int nums[], int length);
void printValues(int *nums, int length);
```

I.e. the size does not matter. Yet, it still does not mean that you can use an invalid array declaration there, i.e. it is illegal to specify a negative or zero size, for example.

(BTW, the same applies to parameters of function type - it immediately decays to pointer-to-function type.)

If you want to enforce array size matching between arguments and parameters, use pointer- or reference-to-array types in parameter declarations

```
void printValues(int (&nums)[3]);
void printValues(int (*nums)[3]);
```

Of course, in this case the size will become a compile-time constant and there's no point of passing `length` anymore.

Comment: Nice catch with negative or zero size in the declaration, i wouldn't have thought of doing that in the first place.

Comment: Neat, I didn't know you could enforce the array size. `(*nums)[3]` doesn't work by the way.

Comment: @Kavon, it does - consider `void f(int (*a)[3]);` vs. `int a[2]; f(&a);`.

Comment: @Kavon: `int (*nums)[3]` works, but requires some extra work. Within the `printValues()` function, you have to refer to elements as `(*nums)[i]`; and the caller must use an extra `&` as in: `printValues(&buf)` (if `buf` is an array). The idea is that instead of using automatic decay, you make explicit pointers, which keep the type more "intact". It is cumbersome, though.

Comment: &Kavon Farvardin: It does work. You just have to remember that in order to get a pointer to something you need the unary `&` operator and in order to access something through a pointer you need the unary `*` operator. So you have to apply `&` to the argument, and apply `*` to the parameter inside the function: `(*nums)[1]` for example.

Answer (score 3):

*<del>I don't see what compile error you are referring to</del>* - arrays passed to a function *decay* to pointers and you lose the array type information. You might as well have used:

```
void printValues(int* nums, int length);
```

You can avoid the decay to pointers by using references:

```
void printValues(int (&nums)[3], int length);
```

Or simply use pointers if you don't want fixed-sized arrays.

Comment: At least with the Visual C++ compiler, it will throw an error if the array's size is <= 0 even if the value will be entirely ignored anyway.

Answer (score -2):

The size of the array is not ignored, it is part of the type of the argument. You should get a compiler error if you try to pass an array of any other size into the function.

On the other hand C and C++ don't do bounds checking on array accesses, so in that sense they *are* ignored.  But that's true in any other context as well, not just for function parameters.

Comment: Not true. In the above declaration, the array size is a part of the syntax, but it has no semantic effect. The parameter declaration is equivalent to `int nums[]` and to `int *nums`. Size is indeed ignored.

Comment: I was under the impression that array size parameters did matter in the case of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: When you pass a multidimensional array, then it probably decays to passing a pointer to array (with one less dimension) - hence the size of all but the first dimension matters.